# Views Date Filter - granularity

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-7, view

I'm having an issue with views date fields. I'm currently filtering a date with minute granularity. This filter is an exposed filter but only shows year, month and day.

I checked in the markup and there's nothing hidden. In fact, when I try to set a default value for the filter it's not showing hour and minute neither.

Then I tried with different date fields from other content types and this issue is still present: granulity works only for day, month and year.

The query shows minute granularity, so I think that my last approach could be altering the query with the values in GET or POST.

So, I want to know if any of you have experienced similar problems, or if anyone can give me some hint of what could be happening.

Thanks!

PD: Most modules seems up to date. Views and Date are updated too.
PD: Date views is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and after hours I finally found my mistake. In my case I hadn't selected the filter value as "Date" when adding the filter.
I corrected the problem by Add filter, set filter to "Date" (right next to search box) and selected "Date: Date (node)". Then set "Date selection form element" and "Granuality"   and in the date fields the desired field you are going to use for filtering. I think this way you 'll solve the problem. In my case it worked. The problem was that i added "Content: Post date" in the exposed filter. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Geoandri for your help. In my case this view was working a few weeks ago. The filter is a date filter, I set the granularity to minute. Then I chose year, month and day, but the controls to set hour and minute do not appear.